# Startup Folder in RememberTheMilk

Tags: remember-the-milk

Can I get [RememberTheMilk](http://RememberTheMilk.com) to start in the "All Tasks" folder when I log in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by skipping the start page.

> Always skip this page

Then go to your settings and Lists Page

`http://www.rememberthemilk.com/home/[your username]/#section.settings`

Select All Tasks go to more Actions and set as default.

This should work.

My default was Personal and I tried using All tasks (logged out and cleared cache).

Comment: My default was somehow stuck on the inbox but after changing it a few times it now works, thansk!